# React Native: How to create an animated border for a loading effect?

Tags: react-native, animation, linear-gradients

Is it possible to create a similar loading animation in React Native?
Here is the link, explaining how to do it using CSS in browser: https://dev.to/chokcoco/fantastic-css-border-animation-5166

[image]